# Laravel 5.5 eloquent value() only pulling through first row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$origin = User::find($request->user_id);

echo $origin->postcode;
```

is giving the correct data, whereas:

```
$origin = User::find($request->user_id)->value('postcode');

echo $origin;
```

is giving incorrect data as it pulls through the first row only, ignoring the user_id.

Same thing happens with `->pluck('postcode');`

This seems unexpected, what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, evidently method `value()` does **not** what you expect.

Diving deep in Laravel core will show you that calling `value()` of Model instance leads to calling `value()` method of a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, which is defined as:

```
/**
 * Get a single column's value from the first result of a query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return mixed
 */
public function value($column)
```

and returns just what it should.

So, you chose a wrong method.